# Serialize not returning value for select dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code that gets a value from unselected options in a select dropdown. This displays in console.log as an array with the correct values. However, `serialize();` is not returning any values for this select when i `console.log(data);`. If I `console.log(boxintake);` this shows me the correct values being passed.

Options are being added from button click and are working correctly. Assume all names and form names are correct.

I would be grateful if someone could enlighten me as to why this is not working. Many thanks.

html

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="labelStyle" for="box_ni">Select Your Box(es)</label><br />
     <select disabled id="box_ni" multiple name="box_ni[]" size="15">
      <option value="">
      </option>
    </select>
    <div id="nidstrmessage"></div>
    <div class="servicesHelp"><lead id="serviceHelp" class="form-text text-muted help">
      Read help <img src="/domain/admin/images/qmark.png" width="24px" height="24px" class="helpintk"/>
      </lead>
    </div>
    <div class="noBrtvBoxes" style="color:white;"></div>
  </div>
```

js

```
$("#USRboxni").submit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

    var boxintake = $("#box_ni option").map(function(){
      return this.value;
     }).get();
     console.log(boxintake);

    var data = $("#USRboxni").serialize();
      console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of issues:

- `.serialize()` will exclude any controls that are `disabled`
- `.serialize()` on a multi select will only return the selected values

As your `select` is both disabled and doesn't have anything actually selected, you get no results.

When you add your items, I suggest you also make them selected at that time; this might solve many of your issues.

That's what `<select multiple` is for - giving the user a number of options and allowing them to select which ones they want.  But you're not using it for that, you're using it as a "the user selected these".  You might be better off using a hidden input store and a div to show the selected values.

Example snippet with disabled removed and one item selected shows that it only returns that one item:

```js
//$("#USRboxni").submit(function(e) {
//e.preventDefault();

var boxintake = $("#box_ni option").map(function() {
  return this.value;
}).get();
console.log(boxintake);

var data = $("#USRboxni").serialize();
console.log(data);
//});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='USRboxni'>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="labelStyle" for="box_ni">Select Your Box(es)</label><br />
  <select /*disabled*/ id="box_ni" multiple name="box_ni[]" size="15">
      <option value="1" selected>one</option>
      <option value="2">two</option>
    </select>
</div>
</form>
```

You could remove the 'disabled' just before `serialize()` then add it back, but you'll still need to select the items.

Comment: The disabled option is only at load stage. It is enabled elsewhere in the code.

Comment: There is a remove option that will let users remove itmes from the listbox. This will mean that they have to select all items before submitting form for processing. Is there not a way to grab the unselected values on submission. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can retrieve the values, you already have the code to do that.  You can't just call `.serialize()` and expect it to do something different from what it's designed/written to do.   So the solution is to not use .serialize but to serialise the form with your own code.

Comment: So would that entail just passing the var to data. ie; var data = boxintake;

Comment: Depends on what else is on your form.  You might need to make some changes to your post action server-side, depends on what you're using server-side whether it would handle it automatically or if you'd need to make a change.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Sorted it this way: `data: {
            user: user,
            company: company,
            service: service,
            dept: dept,
            address: address,
            box: boxintake
        },`

Comment: Nice - glad you got it sorted.